# Ecto query for distinct associated records

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a query that loads all messages in a chatroom:

`room = conn.assigns[:room] |> Repo.preload(messages: from(m in Message, order_by: m.inserted_at))`

I also want to have a `users` variable that's a list of distinct/unique records that created these messages.

I could create a MapSet of `user_ids` from `room.messages`, and then query these users. But I wonder if there is a cleaner & more performant way to accomplish this?

Comment: FYI you don't need `MapSet`. You can use `Enum.uniq` like this: `id in ^Enum.uniq(for m <- messages, do: m.user_id)` (assuming `Message` has a `user_id` field).

Comment: @Dogbert thanks. that's good to know.